# PHP - Flat Associative Array into Deeply nested Array by parent property

Tags: php, recursion, nested, pass-by-reference

I have a problem that has been stressing me out for weeks now and i cannot find a clean solution to it that does not involve recursion.

This is the problem:
Take a flat array of nested associative arrays and group this into one deeply nested object. The top level of this object will have its parent property as null.

This is my solution but i admit it is far from perfect. I am fairly certain this can be done in a single loop without any recursion, but for the life of me i cannot work it out!

```
//Example single fork
$data = array(

    //Top of Tree
    0 => array(
        "name" => "A",
        "parent" => null,
        "id" => 1,
    ),

    //B Branch
    1 => array(
        "name" => "B",
        "parent" => "1",
        "id" => 2,
    ),
    2 => array(
        "name" => "B1",
        "parent" => "2",
        "id" => 3,
    ),
    3 => array(
        "name" => "B2",
        "parent" => "3",
        "id" => 4,
    ),
    4 => array(
        "name" => "B3",
        "parent" => "4",
        "id" => 5,
    ),

    //C Branch
    5 => array(
        "name" => "C",
        "parent" => "1",
        "id" => 6,
    ),
    6 => array(
        "name" => "C1",
        "parent" => "6",
        "id" => 7,
    ),
    7 => array(
        "name" => "C2",
        "parent" => "7",
        "id" => 8,
    ),
    8 => array(
        "name" => "C3",
        "parent" => "8",
        "id" => 9,
    ),

);
```

```
Actual anonymised example
array:7214 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => null
    "id" => 
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  7 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  8 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  9 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
  10 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "parent" => 
    "id" => 
  ]
```

```
Another example deeper nesting 
{
   "name":"top",
   "id":xxx,
   "children":{
      "second":{
         "name":"second",
         "id":xxx,
         "children":{
            "Third":{
               "name":"third",
               "id":xxx,
               "children":{
                  "fourth":{
                     "name":"fourth",
                     "id":xxx
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```
$originalLength = count($data);
$obj = [];
while ($originalLength > 0) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $name = $item['name'];
        $parent = $item['parent'];

        $a = isset($obj[$name]) ? $obj[$name] : array('name' => $name, 'id'=>$item['id']);

        if (($parent)) {

            $path = get_nested_path($parent, $obj, array(['']));
            try {
                insertItem($obj, $path, $a);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                continue;
                //echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
        }

        $obj[$name] = isset($obj[$name]) ? $obj[$name] : $a;
        $originalLength--;
    }
}

echo json_encode($obj['A']);
```

```
function get_nested_path($parent, $array, $id_path)
{

    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $temp_path = $id_path;

            array_push($temp_path, $key);

            if ($key == "id" && $value == $parent) {
                array_shift($temp_path);
                array_pop($temp_path);
                return $temp_path;
            }

            if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 0) {
                $res_path = get_nested_path(
                    $parent, $value, $temp_path);

                if ($res_path != null) {
                    return $res_path;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function insertItem(&$array, $path, $toInsert)
{
    $target = &$array;
    foreach ($path as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $target))
            $target = &$target[$key];
        else throw new Exception('Undefined path: ["' . implode('","', $path) . '"]');
    }

    $target['children'] = isset($target['children']) ? $target['children'] : [];
    $target['children'][$toInsert['name']] = $toInsert;
    return $target;
}
```

Comment: Is it a specific requirement of the task you've been set that you don't use recursion? If not, what's the issue with it? Recursion is a valid solution to many kinds of problem.

Comment: I want to use this on a fairly large data set, around 10,000 items. My current solution is very resource heavy, as it is having to go back through the tree it is building to find the location to insert the child.

Comment: _(looks like an Automattic coding challenge...)_

Comment: Nope not a challenge. This is legit

Comment: `very resource heavy`...so it's slow, or using lots of memory, or both? What are the parameters of what you'd expect in order to make it work the way you want? Is there a max execution time and/or memory use and/or anything else that you'd find acceptable? Have you tried anything so far to optimise it?

Comment: Honestly speaking what i have works. I dispatch a job and the result is persisted in the DB. It takes around a minute. The purpose of this post is to ascertain, is there a simpler cleaner option that i have missed. Ideally i would like this to execute in max two seconds so i could incorporate into a frontend request.

Comment: This is about as optimum as i could get it!

Comment: "clean" isn't necessarily the same as "optimised", so it'd help to be clear on the primary goal. Personally I doubt 2 seconds is realistic in something like PHP, given the volumes of data involved, but maybe it could be speeded up a bit in some areas. have you done any debugging to work out if there's any particular section of the code which takes more time than others? It would be good for people to have a clear starting point and/or a more specific problem statement than just "speed it up" - it has the potential at the moment to be too broad for us here, if a full rewrite is needed.

Comment: Ok lets be more specific about where i feel this could be simplified.

Comment: Ok lets be more specific about where i feel this could be simplified. During the main loop, I am checking to see if that item has a parent, and if so obtaining the path to where is  belongs in my new object and inserting it there. At this point i should be able to just use access the object at the correct location i.e. $obj[$grandParent][$parent][children]. If i could access the array with a string like "[$grandParent][$parent][children]" then this would work, but from what i understand this was depreciated? I think it was curly bracehttps://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take on what I believe is the desired output:

```php
function buildTree(array $items): ?array {

    // Get a mapping of each item by ID, and pre-prepare the "children" property.
    $idMap = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $idMap[$item['id']] = $item;
        $idMap[$item['id']]['children'] = [];
    }

    // Store a reference to the treetop if we come across it.
    $treeTop = null;

    // Map items to their parents' children array.
    foreach ($idMap as $id => $item) {
        if ($item['parent'] && isset($idMap[intval($item['parent'])])) {
            $parent = &$idMap[intval($item['parent'])];
            $parent['children'][] = &$idMap[$id];
        } else if ($item['parent'] === null) {
            $treeTop = &$idMap[$id];
        }
    }

    return $treeTop;
}
```

This does two array cycles, one to map up the data by ID, then one to assign children to parents. Some key elements to note:

- The build of `$idMap` in the first loop also effectively copies the items here so we won't be affecting the original input array (Unless it already contained references).
- Within the second loop, there's usage of `&` to use references to other items, otherwise by default PHP would effectively create a copy upon assignment since these are arrays (And PHP copies arrays on assignment unlike Objects in PHP or arrays in some other languages such as JavaScript). This allows us to effectively share the same array "item" across the structure.
- This does not protect against bad input. It's possible that invalid mapping or circular references within the input data could cause problems, although our function should always just be performing two loops, so should at least not get caught in an infinite/exhaustive loop.

Comment: While the above is brilliant, it does seem to have a flaw. It would appear objects in the array are being overwritten? I am making this assumption as there are items within the original data which are no longer present in the output result! Frustrating! But your answer does go to show that this can achieved without recursion, it is not yet perfect.

Comment: @JamesBaird Are you referring to actual objects? If so, they will behave differently. This solution is built to your provided example input, which has no objects within.

Otherwise, do you have an example of input that fails the desired output? 
Based upon your example input, I see all those items in the output.

Comment: I will avoid using the word object as there is no object. This is an array of associative arrays. I have given two further examples pulled from the actual data source and anonymised. I can conform your solution produces a result where some of the entries are not present. I observed this on level four. I don’t understand why….

Comment: I just ran it again and again got a completely different outcome with entries missing. It is the strangest thing. I know my code is unnecessarily verbose and OTT but the result is always the same. Why is it a solution without recursion seems to fail??

Comment: I will try to create an example i can share where your solution fails. Will try again later this evening.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You can find example data here along with your output and the output from my recursive one https://github.com/peep24/exampleData

Comment: If you are able to help i would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: you can mostly ignore the names as they are more or less random.

Comment: After extensive debugging with the help of Dan managed toconfirm his answer is correct. I had issues with my data.

Comment: You're missing something. if ($item['parent'] === null) condition is never met, you'll return a null $treeTop variable. isn't it?

Comment: @PabloLionelArturi Sure, that could occur, but as I said in the response the function "does not protect against bad input". Even in that case, it would still return as the return type indicates.

Comment: btw, it's an excellent function!

Comment: I would just comment the line         $idMap[$item['id']]['children'] = [];
as most treeview plugins when they find a [children] node, adds a plus sign (+). Commenting this line you add a node when there are child nodes.

Comment: and if you modify $treeTop with $treeTop[] it's going to work if you have more than one root category. Sorry about commenting but I found it great!